# Semaphores and multiple command line processes

Tags: c#, multiprocessing, semaphore

I have a C# command line exe that I am trying to limit to a max of 3 occcurrences. I am using Semaphores. The code is below.

```
private static void Main()
{
    using (Semaphore semaphore = new Semaphore(3, 3, "testing"))
    {
        if (!semaphore.WaitOne(100))
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Sorry too late");
            Environment.Exit(0);
        }

    } 
    Console.WriteLine("Hello world");
    Thread.Sleep(100000000);
}
```

I press CTRL-F5 (run without debugging) three times and my processes fire off and all sleep. I then start a fourth occurence and it runs without a problem.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: I think each thread is making it's own new Semaphore. You also seem to have three processes each of them running one thread and not three threads as you'd like.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Semaphore` objects are special, in that you can give them "system names", as you have done, to make them synchronize across processes.

This means that I was initially incorrect in thinking each process would create its own version, and that was causing your problem.

However, you are using it in a `using` block, so after it has done its work, it disposes it. The next process makes a new one, etc. See [MSDN](http://tinyurl.com/lwupbrk) for a working example of how to do this correctly.

Remove the using block, or alternatively, don't use a `Semaphore` for this, just do:

```
if (Process.GetProcessByName(Process.GetCurrentProcess().ProcessName).Length < 4)
  //You are ok!
```

To check against the number of running instances of your process.

Comment: _"Semaphore objects, like all synchronization primitives, are not used for cross-process synchronization, just cross-thread"_ - Are you sure?  MSDN: _"`Named system semaphores are visible throughout the operating system`, and `can be used to synchronize the activities of processes`. You can create multiple Semaphore objects that represent the same named system semaphore, and you can use the OpenExisting method to open an existing named system semaphore."_  [MSDN](http://tinyurl.com/lwupbrk)

Comment: @MickyDuncan You appear to be correct. I'm reading now to see if he has done something else wrong.

Comment: @MickyDuncan Yep, I had this misdiagnosed. I think I have it now though.

Comment: Looks good.  I wonder if he puts the `Console.WriteLine()` and `sleep` inside the `using` block it may work too?

Comment: @MickyDuncan I suspect that would work better (specifically putting the sleep there).

Comment: Thanks would in never have guessed it was the using block. Will have to decide which route to go down.

Answer (score 1):

In addition to Bradley's fine answer, I wonder if your code should instead read:

```
private static void Main()
{
    using (Semaphore semaphore = new Semaphore(3, 3, "testing"))
    {
        if (!semaphore.WaitOne(100))
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Sorry too late");
            Environment.Exit(0);
        }

        Console.WriteLine("Hello world");
        Thread.Sleep(100000000);
    } 

}
```

...because whilst the program is essentially running, you want to consume the semaphore not release it right away due to the `Dispose()`